# "IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL" when trying to delete a bitmap created by a camera intent in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, android-camera-intent

I have a working piece of code that uses a camera to take a picture. When the picture has been taken, I am receiving it to scale it down and manipulate it in different ways. 
What I want to do is deleting the original saved picture (done automatically by Android) and save my manipulated picture afterwards.

So here is my code for starting the intent:

```
 private void takePicture(){
        File storagePath =  getAlbumStorageDir();
        String timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis()+"";
        File file = new File(storagePath, timeStamp + ".jpg");

        if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            file.delete();
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        capturedImageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, capturedImageUri);
        context.startActivityForResult(i, CameraCapture.REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
    }

private File getAlbumStorageDir() {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), context.getResources().getString(R.string.gallery));
        Log.d("PICTUREVIEW", file.getAbsolutePath());
        if (!file.mkdirs()) {
            Log.e("MyFileStorage", "Directory not created");
        }
        return file;
    }
```

And when it is returned, I am handling it like this:

```
private void manageCapturedPicture() {
    try {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(capturedImageUri);
        context.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    //loadPictures();
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(capturedImageUri));
    int width = LayoutUtil.getScreenWidth(context) * 2;
    if (width > 600) {
        width = 600;
    }
    double ratio = ((double)bm.getHeight() / (double)bm.getWidth());
    double height = width * ratio;
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, width, (int)height, true);

    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    contentResolver.delete(capturedImageUri, null, null);

    imageView.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

As you can see, I am scaling down the image and showing it in an imageview (simply for testing purposes). This was working fine until I attempted to delete the original picture from the external storage.
When I added these to lines:

```
    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    contentResolver.delete(capturedImageUri, null, null);
```

I got the following output (and a crash of course):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {nightout.dk.nightoutandroid/nightout.dk.nightoutandroid.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/nightout/1450477843900.jpg
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3790)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3833)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:152)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1390)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5538)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/nightout/1450477843900.jpg
            at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(ContentResolver.java:1323)
            at nightout.dk.nightoutandroid.views.PicturesView.manageCapturedPicture(PicturesView.java:137)
            at nightout.dk.nightoutandroid.views.PicturesView.receiveStringMessage(PicturesView.java:197)
            at nightout.dk.nightoutandroid.services.eventbus.EventBus.postStringMessage(EventBus.java:39)
            at nightout.dk.nightoutandroid.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:158)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6238)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3786)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3833)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:152)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1390)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5538)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, to delete a file, create a `File` object pointing to that file, and call `delete()` on that `File` object.

Note that since it is possible that you will undergo a configuration change or have your process terminated while the camera app is in the foreground, make sure to save the path to the file in your saved instance state `Bundle` and restore it from there.

With respect to your `manageCapturedPicture()` method:

- Please do not index an image in the `MediaStore` if you intend on deleting it milliseconds later
- Feel free to use `decodeFile()` on `BitmapFactory`, since this is a file that you control
- Please use `BitmapFactory.Options` and scale the image as part of reading it in, rather than wasting nearly twice the heap space by reading in the full image and then scaling it
- Do not try to `delete()` something from a `ContentProvider` that you did not get from the `ContentProvider`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. What would you suggest that I should use to index the image instead of MediaStore? And is it possible to get the full image back from the intent without saving it to the memory?

Comment: @user68621: "What would you suggest that I should use to index the image instead of MediaStore?" -- since you are deleting the image, do not index it. "And is it possible to get the full image back from the intent without saving it to the memory?" -- if by "the memory" you mean a file, you can try implementing a streaming `ContentProvider` that does not store the image to a file, then pass a `Uri` for that `ContentProvider` in `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, though I have not tried this. Outside of that, though, it's either a full-size image on disk, a thumbnail in memory, or don't use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

Comment: Okay.. Well I don't have any experience using the camera through an intent, but it seems a bit "limited" what I can do compared to a camera view (surfaceview). Anyways I have to use the intent for this project. If it's not too much to ask, could you provide an example in your answer on what you would use the camera intent to get a scaled version of the full image image (not a thumbnail), while the original is deleted? I am a bit confused on which approuch I should use right now. I appreciate the help.

Comment: I found a solution to my problem. By following your suggestions I ended up saving the picture as a temporary file in the phones memory. Every time I take a new picture is saved the same place, overriding the old temp file if there are any. And when the cropping (and other editing) is done, the picture is finally saved. Anyways, thanks for your help. I'll accept your answer. If you think my solution could be improved, I would be happy to hear from you again.

Comment: @CommonsWare delete file is not deleting thumbails ,

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar: I am sorry, but I do not know what you mean. You may wish to ask a fresh Stack Overflow question, where you can provide a [mcve] and more details.

Comment: I already asked this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37641409/how-can-i-save-my-bitmap-correctly-for-second-time/37843776#37843776