# How can I save my bitmap correctly for second time?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-bitmap, android-file

I want to save my bitmap to cache directory. 
I use this code:

```
try {
        File file_d = new File(dir+"screenshot.jpg");
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        boolean deleted = file_d.delete();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

    imagePath = new File(dir+"screenshot.jpg");
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

it s working fine. But if I want to save different img to same path, something goes wrong. I mean it is saved to same path but I see it old image, but when I click the image I can see the correct image which I saved second time.

Maybe its come from cache but I do not want to see old image because when I want to share that image with whatsapp old image seen , if i send the image it seems correct.

I want to share saved image on whatsapp like this code:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(imagePath));
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.title_share)),whtsapp_result);
```

How can I fix it?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Best practice is when you save a new image first clear the previous image(Same Name Image) from the directory .

Comment: I delete the prev image as you can see in my code, it is not working?

Comment: check the `deleted` value. If the image deleted then it will never come back .

Comment: i debug the code, I control the file it is deleted but when come back , its small image which before clicked, is wrong

Comment: Sounds like the cached thumbnail is not being refreshed when you replace the file. You should look for a way to refresh the cache. Where do you display the image? Is it in your code or in another app? Sample code would be useful.

Comment: yes but how can I refresh cache? I use saved image to share on whatsapp

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[],%20android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener)) ? It will trigger a media scan. Used like so: `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[]{imagePath}, null, null)`

Comment: can you answer and please show how can use it in my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem like this:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getImageUri(context,bitmap_));
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.title_share)),whtsapp_result);
```

v

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
          ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
          String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "TitleC1", null);
          return Uri.parse(path);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but since you save a new image (with the old name, or another, that’s not relevant) you should fire a media scan to that path so that the media provider is updated with new content.

See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[],%20android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener)):

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[]{imagePath}, null, null);
```

Or even better, wait for the scan to be completed:

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[]{imagePath}, null, new OnScanCompletedListener() {
    @Override
    void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
        // Send your intent now.
    }
});
```

In any case this should be called **after** the new file is saved. As I said, I have not tested and this is just a random guess.

Comment: Sorry about that :-)

Comment: how can I delete thumbnail